# IIS Hosted WCF Rest Service keeeps prompting for Windows Auth Credentials

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, iis, windows-authentication

I have a WCF Rest Service that I'm building.  The service is hosted in IIS under an SSL.  And I have the site in IIS setup to use Windows authentication with Anonymous authentication disabled.

However, when I attempt to navigate to service.svc file in the browser to test the windows authentication I am prompted from my credentials as expected.  However, after entering my credentials it continuous to prompt me over and over.  And I don't know why or what I'm missing.

If I re-enable Anonymous authentication and navigate to the service.svc file then the wsdl data loads..but from my understanding is no longer using windows authentication at that point.

I have tested this in IE and Firefox and both of them do the same thing.

Here is my web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebHttpBindingConfig">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="httpEnabled">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="False" includeWindowsGroups="True"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="myService" behaviorConfiguration="httpEnabled">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="myContract" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBindingConfig" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Any help figuring this out would be great.  If you need any other information please let me know.  Thank you.

Problem:  Continuous prompt for creds when attempting to view Service.svc in browser.
Expected result:  Upon entering valid creds they Service.svc page should load

EDIT:
I was going to post images of the Auth Settings and an example of what it was dong to give a visual, but I don't have enough reputation yet.  Sorry.

Comment: ?           <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>

Comment: message is an unsupported element in the web.config. so that won't work

Comment: The office warning message I get from the web.config when I try the suggested change is:  "The elements security has an invalid child element 'message'. List of possible expected elements: 'transport'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It ended up being a server configuration issue.  I discovered I could load the Service.svc file from a remote machine with valid creds.  So after I did some searching I found the following article:

http://warnajith.blogspot.com/2011/06/iis-75-401-unauthorized-access-error.html

The issue was I needed to DisableLoopbackCheck.  So after I followed the steps on that page to update the registry it loaded correctly

Note:  If you're on a windows 2012 server you do not need to do step 1 in the link provided.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.